# Nested Iron Ajax

Tags: javascript, arrays, polymer, iron

Ok. So my last post was too ambiguous. For my second post, let me try to approach the same problem in hopefully a little more straighforward manner. Below is the code. Here is a screenshot of the results I get. Regarding the second iron-ajax call, if I use curl in terminal with this () I get what I want (it's a link preview service, so title, img, desc etc). Trying to accomplish the same with iron-ajax post with required parameters defined per spec. I don't get any console errors (for the first time) and based on the [object.Object] result I get when I output the last-response variable in the body of second dom-repeat, appears to be returning a json object just like the first iron-ajax call (which does work, includes the link but not enough data about it, hence running link through second service that returns the data I want to display).

**[Result from running code locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmoPJ.png)**

**CODE:**

```
<dom-module id="my-new-view">
<template>
<!-- Defines the element's style and local DOM -->
  <style>
  :host {
    display: block;

    padding: 16px;
  }
</style>
<iron-ajax auto
  url="https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=http://feeds.feedburner.com/DrudgeReportFeed"
  params="{"fmt":"xml-rss"}"
  handle-as="json"
  last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}"></iron-ajax>
<p>First: {{ajaxResponse}}</p>
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ajaxResponse.items]]" as="item" index-as="item_no">
<p>{{item.title}}</p>

<iron-ajax auto
method="post"  
url="https://guteurls.de/api/"
  params="{"u":"{{item.guid}}", "r":"https://127.0.0.1", "e":"s652imb8et42xd0bd", "t":"json"}"
  handle-as="json"
  last-response="{{newAjaxResponse}}"></iron-ajax>

  <p>Second: {{newAjaxResponse}}</p>


  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[newAjaxResponse.newItems]]" as="newItem" index-as="newItem_no">

    <p>{{newItem.title}}</p>
    <paper-card heading="{{newItem.title}}" image="{{newItem.image.url}}" alt="{{newItem.title}}">
      <div class="card-content">
       <h1>Description: {{newItem.desc}}</h1>
       <p>Test</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-actions">{{newItem.title}}
        <paper-button>Share</paper-button>
        <paper-button>Explore!</paper-button>
      </div>
    </paper-card>

</template>
</template>
</template>

<script>
class MyNewView extends Polymer.Element {
static get is() { return 'my-new-view'; }
}



customElements.define(MyNewView.is, MyNewView);


</script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems and Solutions:

1. `params="{"fmt":"xml-rss"}"`

   - Quoting not done properly. You can you single quote as well like
     `params='{"fmt":"xml-rss"}'` or `params="{'fmt':'xml-rss'}"`
2. `First: {{ajaxResponse}}` and `Second: {{newAjaxResponse}}`

   - You can use `console` to debug since you cannot display object like that
3. `params="{"u":"{{item.guid}}", "r":"https://127.0.0.1", "e":"s652imb8et42xd0bd", "t":"json"}"`

   - Quoting not done properly.
   - Attribute binding i.e. `{{item.guid}}` must be followed by `$`.
   - Change to `params$='{"u":"{{item.guid}}", "r":"https://127.0.0.1", "e":"s652imb8et42xd0bd", "t":"json"}'`
4. `newAjaxResponse.newItems`

   - There is no `newItems` in `newAjaxResponse`. Just use `newAjaxResponse`
   - [Note: `newAjaxResponse` is returned as `Object` which must be converted to `Array` since `dom-repeat` works only with `Array`.]
5. Before you define fields like `desc`, `image.url` make sure it exists.

Working code:

```
<dom-module id="my-new-view">
<template>
<!-- Defines the element's style and local DOM -->
  <style>
  :host {
    display: block;

    padding: 16px;
  }
</style>
<iron-ajax auto url="https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=http://feeds.feedburner.com/DrudgeReportFeed" params='{"fmt":"xml-rss"}' handle-as="json" last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}"></iron-ajax>
<p>First: {{ajaxResponse}}</p>
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ajaxResponse.items]]" as="item" index-as="item_no">
  <p>{{item.title}}</p>

  <iron-ajax auto method="post" url="https://guteurls.de/api/" params$='{"u":"{{item.guid}}", "r":"https://127.0.0.1", "e":"s652imb8et42xd0bd", "t":"json"}' handle-as="json" last-response="{{newAjaxResponse}}"></iron-ajax>

  <p>Second: {{newAjaxResponse}}</p>


  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[_toArray(newAjaxResponse)]]" as="newItem" index-as="newItem_no">

   <paper-card heading="{{newItem.title}}" image="{{newItem.img}}" alt="{{newItem.title}}">
     <div class="card-content">
       <h1>Description: {{newItem.description}}</h1>
       <p>Test</p>
     </div>
     <div class="card-actions">{{newItem.title}}
      <paper-button>Share</paper-button>
      <paper-button>Explore!</paper-button>
     </div>
  </paper-card>

  </template>
</template>
</template>

<script>
class MyNewView extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() { return 'my-new-view'; }

  _toArray(obj) {
      var tempArray = [];
      tempArray.push(obj);
      //console.log(tempArray);
      return tempArray;
    }

}



customElements.define(MyNewView.is, MyNewView); 

</script>
</dom-module>
```

You can check the working [demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AVMmxXgBLLmI0CDrzKIh).

Comment: Your response was VERY helpful. I really appreciate you taking the time to point out the syntax errors and even moreso create a plunker demo. There's still a problem, though, even with your demo. I cleaned up my local copy and got the output and format desired EXCEPT the same link passed to the guteurl API is repeated over and over. See here for screenshot from your demo: https://image.prntscr.com/image/IrsyJIbOTZume7Qxi3CxGQ.png

Comment: Oops... Didn't mean to send that yet. I consulted a colleague who is a sophisticated dev and he walked me through this and thus far our only conclusion reached is that there's a bug with nested iron-ajax calls where second call is inside a dom-repeat generated from first. If you run your demo, you'll see (initially) the correct output but then it morphs to where once done loading, it's all the same URL attributes (same image, title, etc). Let me know if you have any insights to offer there.

Comment: Finally, @Ofiscora, I am not clear as to why the first iron-ajax call (which returns an object, that's why I had first: {{ajaxResponse}} in body to confirm, which as you said could also be done in console, that both ajaxResponse and newAjaxResponse were returning objects. But you only noted that the second one needed to be parsed, which works, but I am not clear why the first did not similarly need to be parsed by a function into an array.

Comment: Updated (forked) the plunker you created with the code I'm using now. [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/pWwRmTPA75SckoZ3PdWp?p=info) | paper-card is not available at polygit, strange. Just saw that reported elsewhere but that's a separate issue.

Comment: If you are using `auto` in `iron-ajax` it will load every time a paramater or any of its attribute is modified. In your case you are modifying inside `dom-repeat` so that was obvious to happen. So, put your `iron-ajax` outside don't make it `auto` make a method that will call it after your first `iron-ajax` is completed. Then use `dom-repeat`. You don't have to put `iron-ajax` inside.